# Pull information from a data file?

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, sorting

I have over 170000 entries of data in data file in this format:

```
1479661:-1,1,-1,-898,-769,0.00;-1,2,-1,-96,-1402,0.00;-1,3,-1,117,-1397,0.00;-1,4,-1,-4,-2420,0.00;4,5,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,6,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,7,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,8,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,9,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,10,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,11,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,12,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,13,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,14,-1,5570,4395,0.00;-1,15,-1,913,-3533,0.00;4,16,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,17,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,18,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,19,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,20,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,21,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,22,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,23,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,24,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,25,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,26,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,27,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,28,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,29,-1,5570,4395,0.00;:117,-1397,7,7.00,A,Dead;:

1479662:-1,1,-1,-898,-769,0.00;-1,2,-1,-96,-1402,0.00;-1,3,-1,117,-1392,0.00;-1,4,-1,-6,-2419,0.00;4,5,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,6,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,7,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,8,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,9,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,10,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,11,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,12,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,13,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,14,-1,5570,4395,0.00;-1,15,-1,913,-3533,0.00;4,16,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,17,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,18,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,19,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,20,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,21,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,22,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,23,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,24,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,25,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,26,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,27,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,28,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,29,-1,5570,4395,0.00;:117,-1392,7,7.07,A,Dead;:
```

Now each data array starts with a unique id and i was wondering is there a convenient way to push each entry 1479661 then 1479662 every second to an array and assign the values within the unique id into 6 fields that update.

Now I ask if there is a more convenient way as currently I am using this method:

- Data comprises of three chunks in a single line
- Split the link into chunks

  ```
  var chunkOne = [1479661]; 
  var chunkTwo = [-1,1,-1,-898,-769,0.00,-1,2,-1,-96,-1402,0.00,-1,3,-1,117,-1397,0.00,-1,4,-1,-4,-2420,0.00,4,5,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,6,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,7,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,8,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,9,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,10,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,11,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,12,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,13,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,14,-1,5570,4395,0.00,-1,15,-1,913,-3533,0.00,4,16,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,17,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,18,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,19,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,20,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,21,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,22,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,23,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,24,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,25,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,26,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,27,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,28,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,29,-1,5570,4395,0.00];
  var chunkThree = [117,-1397,7,7.00,"A","Dead"];
  ```

Then get length of each array:

```
var chunkOneLength = chunkOne.length;
var chunkTwoLength = chunkTwo.length;
var chunkThreeLength = chunkThree.length;
```

Pick out the nth value in the array depending on the data chunk:

```
//uniqueID set as first
for (var i = 0; i < chunkOneLength; i = i + 1) {
  // useful code would go here
  alert("This is the unique ID " + chunkOne[i]);
}

//teamval
for (var i = 0; i < chunkTwoLength; i = i + 6) {
  // useful code would go here
  alert("This is the teamVal " + chunkTwo[i]);
}
```

Now the only problem I see with this method, is that the original data array will need to be formatted and separated into chunks every time.

Comment: What is the reason for processing a 100mb data file with javascript on the client side?

Answer (score 0):

As you have a separator on each section i.e. `:` you can actually use `split` to split them up like below and push them into a array and only have to do 2 loops - firstly pushing the split data in a new array and then looping through them and populating the structure.

Please note as long as each chunk of data is separated with `:` this will work with anything even if you expand the data later. obviously it will not work if you remove the `:` separator.

example below:

```js
var splitChucks = [];
var chucks = [ "1479661:-1,1,-1,-898,-769,0.00;-1,2,-1,-96,-1402,0.00;-1,3,-1,117,-1397,0.00;-1,4,-1,-4,-2420,0.00;4,5,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,6,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,7,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,8,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,9,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,10,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,11,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,12,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,13,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,14,-1,5570,4395,0.00;-1,15,-1,913,-3533,0.00;4,16,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,17,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,18,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,19,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,20,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,21,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,22,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,23,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,24,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,25,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,26,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,27,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,28,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,29,-1,5570,4395,0.00;:117,-1397,7,7.00,A,Dead;:", "1479662:-1,1,-1,-898,-769,0.00;-1,2,-1,-96,-1402,0.00;-1,3,-1,117,-1392,0.00;-1,4,-1,-6,-2419,0.00;4,5,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,6,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,7,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,8,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,9,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,10,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,11,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,12,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,13,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,14,-1,5570,4395,0.00;-1,15,-1,913,-3533,0.00;4,16,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,17,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,18,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,19,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,20,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,21,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,22,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,23,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,24,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,25,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,26,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,27,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,28,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,29,-1,5570,4395,0.00;:117,-1392,7,7.07,A,Dead;:"];
  
for (var i = 0; i < chucks.length; i++){
  splitChucks.push(chucks[i].split(':'))
}

for (var h = 0; h < splitChucks.length; h++) {
    alert("This is the unique ID " + splitChucks[h][0]);
    alert("This is the teamVal " + splitChucks[h][1]);
}
```

Hope this helps, this is a much more efficient way to do your task :)

Comment: Hi Josh,Thanks for that, i was thinking of using .split but was unsure how to  tie it in with the data that I had. the teamval data array every 6 values belong to the same category could i just use splitChucks[h][1][1] then splitChucks[h][1][2], splitChucks[h][1][3], etc

Comment: each 6 is that done by using the ;? if so you could use splitChucks[h][1].split(';')[0]; etc does that make sense @RajKaul

Comment: that does make sense however if the value in the array is just a , (comma) it take the value as a , not the number

Comment: is it because the var chucks has been placed as a string "".

Comment: but that was not the initial question @RajKaul i have answered what you wanted and now your asking a different question so please mark as accepted and post another question on here.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var splitChucks = [];
var chucks = [ "1479661:-1,1,-1,-898,-769,0.00;-1,2,-1,-96,-1402,0.00;-1,3,-1,117,-1397,0.00;-1,4,-1,-4,-2420,0.00;4,5,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,6,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,7,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,8,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,9,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,10,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,11,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,12,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,13,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,14,-1,5570,4395,0.00;-1,15,-1,913,-3533,0.00;4,16,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,17,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,18,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,19,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,20,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,21,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,22,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,23,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,24,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,25,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,26,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,27,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,28,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,29,-1,5570,4395,0.00;:117,-1397,7,7.00,A,Dead;:", "1479662:-1,1,-1,-898,-769,0.00;-1,2,-1,-96,-1402,0.00;-1,3,-1,117,-1392,0.00;-1,4,-1,-6,-2419,0.00;4,5,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,6,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,7,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,8,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,9,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,10,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,11,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,12,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,13,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,14,-1,5570,4395,0.00;-1,15,-1,913,-3533,0.00;4,16,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,17,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,18,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,19,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,20,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,21,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,22,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,23,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,24,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,25,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,26,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,27,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,28,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,29,-1,5570,4395,0.00;:117,-1392,7,7.07,A,Dead;:"];
  
for (var i = 0; i < chucks.length; i++){
  splitChucks.push(chucks[i].split(':'))
}

for (var h = 0; h < splitChucks.length; h++) {
    alert("This is the unique ID " + splitChucks[h][0]);
    alert("This is the teamVal " + splitChucks[h][1]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One of the best purposes of an unique ID is to act as an index. So, instead of iterating over your index array (chunkOne), use ID as an Object key!

```
// 1479661:-1,1,-1,-898,-769,0.00;-1,2,-1,-96,-1402,0.00;-1,3,-1,117,-1397,0.00;-1,4,-1,-4,-2420,0.00;4,5,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,6,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,7,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,8,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,9,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,10,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,11,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,12,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,13,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,14,-1,5570,4395,0.00;-1,15,-1,913,-3533,0.00;4,16,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,17,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,18,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,19,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,20,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,21,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,22,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,23,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,24,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,25,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,26,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,27,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,28,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,29,-1,5570,4395,0.00;:117,-1397,7,7.00,A,Dead;:

var data = 
{
    1479661:
    [
        -1,1,-1,-898,-769,0.00,-1,2,-1,-96,-1402,0.00,-1,3,-1,117,-1397,0.00,-1,4,-1,-4,-2420,0.00,4,5,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,6,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,7,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,8,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,9,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,10,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,11,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,12,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,13,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,14,-1,5570,4395,0.00,-1,15,-1,913,-3533,0.00,4,16,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,17,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,18,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,19,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,20,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,21,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,22,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,23,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,24,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,25,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,26,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,27,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,28,-1,5570,4395,0.00,4,29,-1,5570,4395,0.00,117,-1397,7,7.00,"A","Dead"
    ]
    // More data...
};

Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key)
{
     console.log('This is ID ' + key);

     data[key].forEach(function(value,index,array)
     {
          console.log('Index ' + index + ' of data key ' + key + ':');
          console.log(data[key][index]);
     });
});
```

Test this on any modern browser's console or node.js instance to see results.